# New Instagram API Change

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

So for an app I have been developing for a long time, I need to

```
GET /users/self/follows
GET /users/self/followed-by
```

Even though it was `deprecated immediately:`

Is this permanent! Is there any way around this!

Is there no way to get followers?

Comment: Check the API docs.

Comment: How and where??

Comment: No, I mean if you  look at the docs you'll see that you cannot (via the API). There's been quite a bit of stuff deprecated, AFAICT without warning (which is kind of a jerk on their part, but hey).

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer possible through Instagram API. You will have find a way to scrape the website itself for this data. You will only be able to get follower count, following count, and photo count

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using Instagram API also called Instagram Platform API, But Facebook announced new set of APIs called Instagram Graph API.

These APIs will be used for any future commercial application.
Here is documentation for same.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api